# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 small text by side

Tags: visual-studio, text, text-editor

I searched how to enable one think. I don't know how it's called so I'll try to explain. It's a small text of all your code, usually in right side. I think it's text editor extention.

Thank you in advice!

Comment: n order to get answer to your question, you must have to follow Guidelines defined by Stack Overflow. This incomplete question and event I am not sure what are you trying to ask. Please edit your question and give more details. Refer [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for clear understanding on how to ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to enable is the enhanced scroll bar. Specifically, **map mode**, which displays code on the scroll bar. It looks like this:

[image]

To enable it: Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages (or whatever language you want) → Scroll Bars → Use map mode for vertical scroll bar.

[image]